# How to debug in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there something special I need to debug in Pycharm?

I have the following code:

```
def main():
    print "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and I have breakpoints on each. I hit Debug and it gives me some windows and prints both lines even though I have breakpoints on each. Is there any kind of indicator when a breakpoint is hit?

[image]

I have seen in other posts something about how you must setup your configuration first? But none of the posts seem to mention how. Here is my configuration

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please do not link me here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/debugging.html I have read it and do not understand what I need to do. I keep getting reffered to lines such as:

> In the Project Structure dialog box, configure the roots, dependencies
>   and libraries to be passed to the interpreter .

I am new to python and am not sure what I should be inputting into the boxes.

So my question is really.

1. Is Pycharm supposed to debug python out of the box?
2. How do I setup Pycharm to debug python if not.

I am using the latest python 2.7.9 a fresh install of a few minutes ago.

Comment: Make sure to have your working directory set to encompass all of the code you are trying to breakpoint.

Comment: I am also confusing with this debugging settings. I choose the right script and set the script parameters. And I click debug button, but the debug tab in the bottom seems going wrong. I confirmed the right setting in the plain terminal. The original pdb debugger in python is really hard to use. I just add more details about this question and wait for the useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out I am just a idiot. Though I have seen people in the debug menu complaining about the same problem.

You are debugging. The breakpoint does not change to indicate you have hit that line like visual studio. Instead one of your lines will change a light blue (depending on your theme) to indicate you are debugging that line.

Answer (score 1):

You set breakpoints in the gutter by clicking a wee bit to the right of the line numbers (if visible)...

[image]

...and run under the "Debug" context (it's the green icon that looks like a bug of some kind).