# pycharm debugger not working properly

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am doing simple python coding in pycharm but the problem is whenever I debug it starts debugging some other file in my project and not the one I am working with.

I did go to run-->edit configuration and check if my file was set for debugging and it was but still it debugs another file when I start debugging.

any help will be appreciated

Comment: How are you running debug? Right clicking? Hitting ctrl-d? What are your debug script and parameters?

Comment: I did it using run-->debug-->selecting my file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you debug using pressing `SHIFT-F9` it debugs the last file you debugged, which might be some file you debugged yesterday...

To debug a new file press `ALT-SHIF-F9`.

You can see these two different debugging options from the `Run` menu. There is `Debug <last file>` and there is `Debug...`

Comment: no still the same I even tried to run some different files from the project but debugging still works for only one particular file

Comment: I removed the python file from the project and debugging works fine for all python file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with Right clicking on body of codes and select your project name form there.
Also can select `Run` > `Debug`

you can debug it line by line from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687771/how-to-debug-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

The saving python files with the python module name causing debugging issues.
Replace the files with other name it will work.